# linked list inside linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

i want to implement a program that used linked list inside linked lists(it simulates a supermarket traffic for your information) doing add,remove,delete etc operations.Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct cash_queue cash;
typedef struct client client;
typedef struct item item;
int k,c;//k== cash registers,c == customers
struct item{
  int value;
  struct item* next;
};

struct cash_queue{
   int cash_num;
   struct client *first;
   struct cash_que* next;
};  

struct client{
  int client_num;
  int items;
  struct item *fitem;
  struct client* next;
};
void create_item(item* fitem){ 
  item *item,*cur;
  cur=fitem;
  item=malloc(sizeof(item));
  printf("give product value\n");
  int v;
  scanf(" %d",&v);
  item->value=v;
  printf("value: %d\n",item->value);
  item->next=NULL;
  while (cur->next)
   cur=cur->next;
  cur->next=item;
} 

void create_queue(client* first){
  client *client,*cur;
  cur=first;    
  client=malloc(sizeof(client));
  printf("how many items this client has?\n");
  int x,i;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  client->items=x;
  client->next=NULL;
  client->fitem=malloc(sizeof(item));
  for (i=1;i<=x;++i)
    create_item(client->fitem);
  while (cur->next){
    cur=cur->next;
  }
  cur->next=client;
}
int main(){
   cash* ncash;
  ncash=malloc(sizeof(cash));
  ncash->cash_num=1;
  ncash->next=NULL;
  ncash->first=malloc(sizeof(client));
      printf("give the number of starting customers\n");
  scanf("%d",&c);
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<=c;++i)
    create_queue(ncash->first);
  }
```

When i try to execute this code my program get aborted.here is the exact output:

```
 give the number of starting customers
 3
 how many items this client has?
 1
 give product value
  2
 value: 2
 aa: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char              *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size        & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
  Aborted
```

Can you tell me why is this happening and how can i fix it? Thanks.Are there any other problems i should correct in my code?

Comment: An assertion encoded into the `malloc()` function failed.  Supposing that that function uses assertions as intended, that means that a supposed invariant on which that function relies (and given in the text of the error message) was found at runtime to not be satisfied.  This very likely results from your code overrunning the bounds of dynamically allocated storage, using a pointer after the block to which it once pointed was freed, or double-freeing a pointer.

Comment: `item=malloc(sizeof(item));` -->> `item=malloc(sizeof *item);` for a start. (and a good reason not to name your objects the same as your types. Or even better: don't use typedefs at all)

Comment: One thing I noticed: you have `void create_item(item* fitem)`.  It looks like it constructs a new item.  But it doesn't actually return that item; it loses it.  If you were hoping top use the `fitem` parameter to pass back the new item, this is not the way to do it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, using the same identifier for a type name `foo` and a variable name `foo` is asking for trouble when you do `sizeof(foo)`. It will use whichever one is in the innermost scope.

Comment: I suggest renaming your types from `foo` to `foo_t` to avoid confusion, or just get rid of the typedefs and use `struct foo` instead.

Comment: wildplasser: i created the function `create_item`  the same way i made  `create_queue ` as you can see.Before `create_queue` worked fine.why i must change `item=malloc(sizeof(item));` to this? `item=malloc(sizeof *item);`  can you explain it to me? thanks

Comment: `client=malloc(sizeof(client));`. What value will `sizeof(client)` return? `sizeof(struct client)` or `sizeof(struct client *)`?

Comment: Steve Summit: I use `fitem` as a head node input.

Comment: @IanAbbott, beware.  POSIX reserves the type suffix `_t` for itself and implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's true, but I've been using `_t` for [at least] two decades and have never had a conflict [it's also a common practice]. The probability is _low_. It requires that one add a `#include` for a _new_ posix `.h` in the same file with a conflict, so if you only include in other files, you're fine. Also, if you have to resolve the conflict, it's an easy global edit to change (e.g. `client_t` into `myclient_t`). (i.e.) A one time event to fix. Also, IMO, it's hubris for posix to prereserve all `_t`. I'd be fine with a prefix: (like `posix_madvise`) or `posix_caddr_t`

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, the error message probably means you are misusing dynamically allocated memory in some way.  Looking at your code, that indeed appears to be the case.  You have multiple instances of this pattern:

```
typedef struct foo foo;

struct foo {
    // elements ...
};

void f() {
    foo *foo;
    foo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    // ... populate foo ..
}
```

You have therein confused yourself, or the compiler, or both by trying to be too clever.  Both `foo`s in the statement containing the `malloc()` call are the same thing: the *variable* `foo`, which is a pointer of type `struct foo *`.  Unless the size of `struct foo` happens to be identical to that of a pointer on your system, that is the wrong thing to do.  If the struct is larger than a pointer, then writing to some of its members will indeed overrun the allocated bounds.

There are several ways you could address this.  I would certainly recommend that you be a little more distinctive in naming.  I would suggest that you do away with the typedefs, too -- your types are not so complex that you gain much by them, and it costs you code clarity.  Additionally, I recommend this form for *all* your `malloc()` calls:

```
bar = malloc(n * sizeof(*bar));
```

Observe that that is clear in allocating a number of bytes that is a multiple of the size of the type of object to which the target pointer points, yet it does not depend directly on what the type of `bar` actually is.  Overall, then:

```
struct bar {
    // elements ...
};

void f() {
    struct bar *temp_bar;
    temp_bar = malloc(sizeof(*temp_bar));
    // ... populate temp_bar ..
}
```

Comment: In your opinion should i just change the name of the variables or stop using `typedef` at all?

Comment: The suggestions in my answer are cumulative.  I recommend all of them together, as demonstrated in my example.  However, any one of them would be sufficient by itself to solve the actual problem.  But beware: your code has additional problems beyond the one you asked about, as described in some of the comments on the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer it was very helpful.You said that my code has additional problems.Can you point them?

Comment: @JohnVn Follow [other] John's advice. But, I'd change the variable names. (e.g.) In `create_queue`, you have `client *client,*cur`. Using `cur` is fine--it is _descriptive_ of its function. But, `client` is vague as to role [yes, it's a `client` type, but _which_ one for _which_ purpose?]. I'd rename it to `new` [not valid in `c++`] or `newclient` so that it's more descriptive and avoids the conflict.